# Why coinbase official library python and nodejs are deprecated in github?

Tags: blockchain, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

Try contacting the coinbase support team but I have no answer.

I am interested in using your api, but I don't understand why it changes the "python and nodejs" official libraries to "deprecated".

Anyone have news?

https://github.com/coinbase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCGXe.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask].  Your question is off-topic since it's asking about a company's development work not your own programming question.  Try doing a google search or posting in a coinbase discussion forum, discord, etc.

Comment: Belive me, I did that!.

Comment: did you ever find out an answer and which libraries to use?